# How to avoid black screen in Android when cordova is loading first time?

Tags: android, cordova

I am using Cordova plugin in my application. I am getting black screen first time when Cordova is loading. It is coming only in **S2,S3,S4 and low end device**.

This is my Config.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0"
    id="myPlugin.android"
    version="0.0.1"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" >

    <feature name="MyPlugin" >
        <param
            name="android-package"
            value="MyPlugin" />
    </feature>

    <preference
        name="backgroundColor"
        value="0xffffffff" />

</widget>
```

Comment: It will great help if any one point out, Why this question is wrong /minus. I see black screen first time in many device while using Cordova .

Answer (score 1):

You can either add a loading dialog that looks like this:

```
<preference name="LoadingDialog" value="APPNAME"/>
```

Or splashcreens https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/blob/master/doc/index.md